# Como puedo filtrar un array para que no se repitan los elementos'

Tags: javascript, array

Como estan?

Les cuento, tengo el siguiente problema que no se como ordenarlo y quizas me podrian dar una mano. Se los ejemplificare con Papa e hijos.

Estoy recuperando desde un metodo suscribe varios objetos de tipo PAPA.

Cada uno de esos PAPAS tiene su ID y varios datos más, entre ellos un subarray HIJOS, cada uno con su propio ID.

Existe el caso de que estos ID de PAPAS pueden repetirse en la lista, pues el suscribe va a buscar a partir del ID de sus hijos, entonces finalmente termino teniendo un resultado asi:

```
PAPA 1, HIJO 1
PAPA 1, HIJO 2
PAPA 1, HIJO 3
PAPA 2, HIJO 1
PAPA 3, HIJO 1
```

Esto es un problema pues lo que necesito listar es solamente a los PAPAS, por tanto necesito realizar un filtro que me detecte a los PAPAS repetidos y solo los liste una vez.

Algo asi:

```
PAPA 1
PAPA 2
PAPA 3
```

Cabe decir que cada objeto PAPA tiene a sus HIJOS dentro, por lo que solo me basta listarlo una vez.

Como podria ordenar un ciclo que vaya primero a recorrer a los PAPAS y me genere un arreglo con los PAPAS sin repetir?

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo del código que necesitas con JavaScript Vanilla

```
var x = [1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,7]
var uniqs = x.filter(function(item, index, array) {
  return array.indexOf(item) === index;
})
console.log(uniqs); // [ 1, 2, 5, 6 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar Setters, aquí te dejo un ejemplo fácil de implementar,
la función set se utiliza para eliminar la duplicidad de datos en un arreglo

```
let chars = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B']; 
let uniqueChars = [...new Set(chars)];            
console.log(uniqueChars);
```

al pasar el arreglo por la función New Set(), obtenemos el resultado final sería: ['A', 'B', 'C']

Comment: Hola ysidro, bienvenido y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.

Comment: Las respuestas no se pueden cerrar... Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona el código. Lee [answer].

Comment: La respuesta está bien. Usando un `Set` se soluciona el problema. La brevedad es que no hay mucho más que decir al respecto